# Activity.OnCreate is called twice

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In an Android app, the Splash screen of my app is called twice.

I have used ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden to avoid recreation for screen orientation and other reasons, but it still is called twice.

Is there a function or way to get the reason about why is called twice?

UPDATE:

I know it is called twice for a log file. I want to avoid to be called twice because OnCreate initializes some global instances.

Comment: is it calling after you rotate the device?

Comment: _Your issue_ can be prevented by not using splash screens entirely, or by using them the right way. Read https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: It's not really ideal practice but you could add in a static bool and wrap your initialization logic in an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

if you rotate this device you activity will be recreate no matter what (This is expected behaviour). using config flag you can only retain data on screen. if dont want activity to be recreated try with orientation lock for activity.